# how rust macros use + separator?

Tags: rust, macros

I wrote a macro:

```
macro_rules! test {
    ($trait:tt<$($param:literal)+>) => {
        {
            println!("{}", stringify!($($param)++));
        }
    };
}
```

for the `$param` repeat separator, I couldn't use the `+` char which is the repeat 'op'.

The output looks like `1 2 3 +` but how can I make it be `1 + 2 + 3` instead?